# Form not updated when values of binded store are changed

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, binding

I have a form with various elements. For example a combobox, here the View part:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel : 'Position de la commission',
labelAlign : 'top',
padding:'20 0 0 0',
displayField: 'parametreLibelle',
valueField: 'parametreValeur',

queryMode: 'local',
bind : {
    value: '{argumentairePosition}',
    store : '{positionsCommissionStore}'
},
reference : 'argumentairePosition',
itemId:'argumentairePosition',
listeners: {
    click: {
        element: 'inputEl',
        fn: 'onArgumentairePositionClick'
    }
}
```

I call a function which should change the selected value in the combobox:

```
onAmendementReferenceChange: function() {
    let me = this;
    let amdtId = this.lookupReference('amendementDeReference').value;
    me.ajaxRequest({
        url: '/eloi/grille/changerAmendementReferenceArgumentaire',
        method: 'GET',
        params: { amdtId: amdtId },
        successFn: function (record) {
            let serverResponse = record && record.responseText ? Util.decodeJson(record.responseText) : undefined;
            let formulaireData = serverResponse ? serverResponse.data : undefined;

            if (formulaireData) {
                let vm = me.getViewModel();
                let store = vm.get('argumentaireRendreIdentiqueStore').first();

                store.set('argumentaireObjet', formulaireData.argumentaireObjet);
                store.set('argumentaireTexte', formulaireData.argumentaireTexte);
                store.set('argumentairePosition', formulaireData.argumentairePosition); // Breakpoint here
                store.set('argumentairePositionRapporteur', formulaireData.argumentairePositionRapporteur);
                store.set('argumentaireAmendementId', formulaireData.argumentaireAmendementId);

                //me.getView().refreshView();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in my browser at the line indicated by a comment, I can see that the value of the store is actually changing (watching `store.get('argumentaireObjet')` in the debugger before and after the line), but the content of my form is not updated in my page. And I can't get why. Any idea?

I tried various tricks to refresh the form, but normally, the binding should do. I shouldn't have to refresh. What am I missing?

I'm using ExtJS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is actually working. I needed to change the value in the ViewModel, not in the Store.

```
onAmendementReferenceChange: function() {
    let me = this;
    let amdtId = this.lookupReference('amendementDeReference').value;
    me.ajaxRequest({
        url: '/eloi/grille/changerAmendementReferenceArgumentaire',
        method: 'GET',
        params: { amdtId: amdtId },
        successFn: function (record) {
            let serverResponse = record && record.responseText ? Util.decodeJson(record.responseText) : undefined;
            let formulaireData = serverResponse ? serverResponse.data : undefined;

            if (formulaireData) {
                let vm = me.getViewModel();
                vm.set('argumentaireObjet', formulaireData.argumentaireObjet);
                vm.set('argumentaireTexte', formulaireData.argumentaireTexte);
                vm.set('argumentairePosition', formulaireData.argumentairePosition);
                vm.set('argumentairePositionRapporteur', formulaireData.argumentairePositionRapporteur);
                vm.set('argumentaireAmendementId', formulaireData.argumentaireAmendementId);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What troubles me is that I'm pretty sure that the initial version, where I'm modifying the Store, worked at a certain point, and stopped working when I made changes related to other issues.